# jquery dynamic if condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have:

```
    var data = [
    {"a":some_value, "b":some_value},
    {"a":some_value, "b":some_value, "c":some_value},
    {"a":some_value, "b":some_value},
```

then:

```
    var keywords = [
    [{key: "a",value: 1}],
    [{key: "b",value: 1},{key: "b",value: 2}]
    ];
```

so i need to find data has ((a=1) AND (b=1 or b=2)):

```
    filteredData = $.grep(data, function (value, i) {
        if (value[keywords[0][0].key] !== keywords[0][0].value) return false;
        if (value[keywords[1][0].key] !== keywords[1][0].value) && (value[keywords[1][1].key] !== keywords[1][1].value)return false;
        return true;
    });
```

everything is ok, but now i need work by dynamic data, keywords, i can't do this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
var array  = $.grep(data, function(obj, idx){
    return keywords.every(function(list, idx, src){
        return list.some(function(item, idx, src){
            return obj[item.key] == item.value
        });
    });
});
console.log(array)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8TNNz/)

For IE < 9 support, you may have to include the pollyfills for

- [Array.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every#Compatibility)
- [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#Compatibility)

Comment: I like this better than my answer. :)

Comment: @Arun P Johny let me check.

Comment: @Arun P Johny how should i (download and) include pollyfillls?

Comment: @mohammadadibi https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim, this is the polyfill I personally use.

Comment: @OneOfOne if i include es5-shim, i can use every and some feature in ie<9 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
filteredData = $.grep(data, function(value, i) {
    for (var k = 0; k < keywords.length; k++) {
        var matched = false;
        var orlist = keywords[k];
        for (var l = 0; l < orlist.length; l++) {
            if (value[orlist[l].key] == orlist[l].value) {
                matched = true;
                break;
        }
        if (!matched) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is great but it's not the answer to everything, for this specific case, it can be simply done with just good ol' plain Javascript :

```
var data = [
    {"a":1, "b":100},
    {"a":1, "b":2, "c":3},
    {"a":2, "b":10}
];
var keywords = [
    [{key: "a",value: 1}],
    [{key: "b",value: 1},{key: "b",value: 2}]
];
function filter(data, keywords) {
    var ret = [];
    for(var i = 0, d, m; i < data.length; ++i) {
        d = data[i];
        m = true;
        for(var x = 0; x < keywords.length && m; ++x) {
            for(var k = 0; k < keywords[x].length && m; ++k) {
                var rule = keywords[x][k];
                console.log(d, d[rule.key] === rule.value, rule);
                m = m && rule.key in d && d[rule.key] === rule.value;
            }
            if(m) break;
        }
        if(m) ret.push(d);
    }
    return ret;
}
console.log(filter(data, keywords));
```

This is the es5 version, without jQuery (can be used with the [es5-shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim) for older browsers) :

```
function es5_grep(data, keywords) {
    return data.map(function(row) {
        return keywords.every(function(list){
            return list.some(function(item){
                return row[item.key] === item.value
            });
        }) ? null : row;
    }).filter(function(v) { return !!v; });
}
```

This is just for future reference, https://stackoverflow.com/a/22512882/145587 is the proper answer for using jQuery.

Comment: what do you think of Arun P Johny solution? that's very short.

Comment: His answer is the proper one for jquery, however it depends on javascript features that will need extra files to run on older / broken browsers.

Comment: i test your code in my real program, it returns wrong answer.

Comment: I tested it against the dataset you provided, maybe give more code to test against?

Comment: i'll check it again,but before that tell me which of them is better include es5-shim and use it, or first code?

Comment: not working, i changed your idea like this and work:         filteredSearchData = $.grep(searchData, function (value, i) {
            for (var i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
                var flag = false;
                for (var j = 0; j < keywords[i].length; j++) {
                    if (value[keywords[i][j].key] === keywords[i][j].value) {
                        flag = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (flag == false) return false;
            }
            return true;
        });